# How to fetch exact url 

Tags: perl, wordpress, lwp-useragent

Can anyone please guide about how we can get exact url and store in a string from wordpress post id eg   htttp://www.domain.com/?p=444
If we visit this above postid url, it takes users to exact url http://www.domain.com/posturl/ so i need help with short lwp perl code to return this "exact url" and print it etc

any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`base`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aResponse#r-base) method from [`HTTP::Response`](http://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aResponse) will get you the absolute URI:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $lwp      = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $lwp->get('http://www.domain.com/?p=444');
print $response->base;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to get the post ID. Some themes use the [`the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) and add its value to a single post. Some don’t.

Even if you know the ID you cannot tell what the matching URI is. The URI is build by [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink), and this function is not available from the outside. Plus, permalinks may change at any time when the owner change the permalink structure.